# Vimeo Embed Full Screen Not Working In Chrome When Using Accordion WordPress Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So I've been researching for about 3 hours now and from what I've read Google Chromes animation update is causing the issue with Vimeo videos not showing the full screen button, or not allowing the video to go full screen.  The issue I'm having is the video not opening to full screen when inside the WordPress accordion shortcode within Visual Composer.  Here's a link the an example:

https://dynatrap.com/how-to-videos/

I've already tried to use a plug-in that allows me to add the webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen attributes and I've also tried to add a custom css class and use the "animation-fill-mode: none !important;" and neither have worked.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include a summary of what you have tried and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help. Please review [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out!

I had to go through and add the CSS style "animation-fill-mode:none !important;" to all of the elements surrounding the embed code and now it works!